# pending intent not triggering

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

The app I am developing will allow the user to set timings for the device to activate silent and normal mode in a specific time interval. Up til now I can get user input of start and end time but can't get the device to be silent mode in that time. To activate silent and normal mode I am using pending intent and broadcast-receiver. Here is what I have coded so far.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etMeal,etDesert,start,end;
Button btnAdd,btnView,btnsttime,btnend;
DatabaseHelper myDB;
int mHour,mMinute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    btnsttime=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sttime);
    btnend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.endtime);

    etMeal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMeal);
    //etDesert = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDesert);
    start=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.stime);
    end=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etime);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String meal = etMeal.getText().toString();
            //String desert = etDesert.getText().toString();

            if(meal.length() != 0){
                AddData(meal);
                etMeal.setText("");
                //etDesert.setText("");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must fill in the text fields!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_Foods.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public void AddData(String meal) {

    boolean insertData = myDB.addData(meal);

    if (insertData == true) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Successfully Inserted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong :(.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void start(View view)
{
    // Get Current Time
   /* Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);*/

   Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                Calendar newTime=Calendar.getInstance();

                    newTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    newTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    String Gottime=String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+":"+String.valueOf(minute);
                    start.setText(Gottime);

                    //mHour=newobj.get(hourOfDay);
                    //mMinute=newobj.get(minute);

                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    //create a pending intent to be called at midnight
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Pending Intent started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    PendingIntent midnightPI = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent("applications.recyclerview1.SilenceBroadCastReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day

                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, midnightPI);

                }
            },calendar.get((Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)),calendar.get((Calendar.MINUTE)), true);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

public void end(View view)
{
    // Get Current Time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    final Calendar newobj2=Calendar.getInstance();

    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {

                    end.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    newobj2.get(hourOfDay);
                    newobj2.get(minute);

                    //create a pending intent to be called at 6 AM
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    PendingIntent sixPI = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent("applications.recyclerview1.UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    //schedule time for pending intent, and set the interval to day so that this event will repeat at the selected time every day

                    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newobj2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sixPI);

                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

SilentBroadCastReceiver.java

```
public class SilenceBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}}
```

UnsilentBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audio=(AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
}}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="applications.recyclerview1">

        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".View_Foods"></activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SilenceBroadCastReceiver">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="applications.recyclerview1.SilenceBroadCastReceiver" >

                </action>

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

          <receiver android:name=".UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver">

            <intent-filter>



       <action 
       android:name="applications.recyclerview1.UnsilenceBroadcastReceiver" >

                </action>

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
        </application>

        </manifest>
```

Comment: which android version are you testing on?

Comment: @SaranSankaran on android version:5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`if you want to broadcast some message from pendingItnent. You are using `getService`.